# Why use BitPat of Seq[(BitPat, T)] in chisel3.util.Lookup.scala

Tags: chisel

Is there any advantage about this method?

```scala
object Lookup {
  def apply[T <: Bits](addr: UInt, default: T, mapping: Seq[(BitPat, T)]): T =
    ListLookup(addr, List(default), mapping.map(m => (m._1, List(m._2))).toArray).head
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to construct a lookup table that can match arbitrary bits in the `addr`.  `BitPat` allows user to define don't care bits. There aren't to many example usages but check out this one in [/ucb-bar/riscv-mini
in /src/main/scala/mini/CSR.scala](https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-mini/blob/master/src/main/scala/mini/CSR.scala). The code uses `BitPat`s that select relevant bits in `csr_addr`.